# why '\97' ascii value equals 55

Tags: c, ascii

Just like *C* code：

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
      char c = '\97';
      printf("%d",c);
      return 0;
}
```

the result is `55`，but I can't understand how to calculate it. 
I know the  Octal number or hex number follow the '\', does the `97` is hex number?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\` is a octal escape sequence but `9` is not a valid octal digit so instead of interpreting it as octal it is being interpreted as a multi-character constant a `\9` and a `1` whose value is implementation defined. Without any warning flags `gcc` provides the following warnings by default:

```
warning: unknown escape sequence: '\9' [enabled by default]
warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
```

The C99 draft standard in section `6.4.4.4` *Character constants* paragraph *10* says (*emphasis mine*):

> An integer character constant has type int. The value of an integer character constant
>   containing a single character that maps to a single-byte execution character is the
>   numerical value of the representation of the mapped character interpreted as an integer.
>   **The value of an integer character constant containing more than one character (e.g.,
>   'ab'), or containing a character or escape sequence that does not map to a single-byte
>   execution character, is implementation-defined**.

For example `gcc` implementation is documented [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Implementation_002ddefined-behavior.html) and is as follows:

> The compiler evaluates a multi-character character constant a character at a time, shifting the previous value left by the number of bits per target character, and then or-ing in the bit-pattern of the new character truncated to the width of a target character. The final bit-pattern is given type int, and is therefore signed, regardless of whether single characters are signed or not (a slight change from versions 3.1 and earlier of GCC). If there are more characters in the constant than would fit in the target int the compiler issues a warning, and the excess leading characters are ignored.
>
> For example, 'ab' for a target with an 8-bit char would be interpreted as ‘(int) ((unsigned char) 'a' * 256 + (unsigned char) 'b')’, and '\234a' as ‘(int) ((unsigned char) '\234' * 256 + (unsigned char) 'a')’.

As far as I can tell this is being interpreted as:

```
char c = ((unsigned char)'\71')*256 + '7' ;
```

which results in `55`, which is consistent with the *multi-character constant* implementation above although the translation of `\9` to `\71` is not obvious.

**Edit**

I realized later on what is really happening is the `\` is being dropped and so `\9 -> 9`, so what we really have is:

```
c = ((unsigned char)'9')*256 + '7' ;
```

which seems more reasonable but still arbitrary and not clear to me why this is not a straight out error.

**Update**

From reading *The Annotated C++ Reference Manual* we find out that in *Classic C* and older versions of C++ when backslash followed character was not defined as an scape sequence it was equal to the numeric value of the character. ARM section `2.5.2`:

> This differs from the interpretation by Classic C and early versions of C++, where the value of a sequence of a blackslash followed by a character in the source character set, if not defined as an escape sequence, was equal to the numeric value of the character. For example '\q' would be equal to 'q'.

Answer (score 5):

\9 is not a valid escape, so the compiler ignores it and ascii '7' is 55.

I would not depend on this behavior, it's probably undefined. But that's where the 55 came from.

edit: Shafik points out it's not undefined, it's implementation defined. See his answer for the references.

Answer (score 2):

`\9` isn't a valid escape sequence, so it's likely falling back to a plain `9` character.

This means that it's the same thing as `'97'`, which is <strike>undefined</strike> implementation defined (see Shafik Yaghmour's answer) behavior (2 characters can't fit into 1 character...).

---

To avoid things like this in the future, consider cranking up the warnings on your compiler. For example, a minimum for `gcc` should be `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Ah. I haven't used default compiler settings in a long time, so did not know that. If that's the case though, the OP should have already seen the warnings and been able to figure it out from there.... :/

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I'm going to assume your code should read this, because it matches your title.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  char c = '\97';
  printf("%d",c);
  return 0;
}
```

`\9` isn't valid, thus let's just assume the character is actually 7. `7` is ascii 55, which is the answer that was printed out.

I'm not sure what you wanted, but `\97` isn't it...