# How to get hexadecimal val of char in c

Tags: c, hex, decimal

So im new to C and im so confused. I dont know how to get a hexadecimal value of a char.

how would i get the chars hexadecimal val below???

`char a = 'a';`

Comment: There's no such thing as a hexadecimal value. There are values and there are representations. Values are independent of representations. 65 == 'A' == 085

Comment: @torstenvl In [65 == 'A' == 085](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68878838/how-to-get-hexadecimal-val-of-char-in-c/68879064#comment121729112_68878838), what is 085?

Comment: @torstenvl: [should be 081 for octal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68878838/how-to-get-hexadecimal-val-of-char-in-c?noredirect=1#comment121769552_68878838)?  8 is usually not considered a valid octal digit.  Perhaps `0101`?

Comment: @chux 085 is a series of brainfarts wrapped in an embarrassing little package. Maybe I should stop commenting on SO late at night.

Comment: @torstenvl We've all been there. (But take heart, 4 others up-voted the comment with the brainfart, so you are not alone. ([K&R C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19901347/2410359) identified 8,9 as octal digts too)

Answer (score 4):

With `char a = 'a';`, `a` has a *value*.  Depending on how we want to see that value:

To print that value as a ([ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)) character: `printf("%c\n", a);`

To print its value in decimal: `printf("%d\n", a);`

To print its value in hexadecimal: `printf("%x\n", a);`

In all 3 cases, the value in `a` is promoted to an `int` as an argument to a `...` function. It is that `int` code is printing.

---

As a `char` may be *signed* or *unsigned*, additional considerations are needed when `a < 0` or in rare implementations where `char` is as wide as an `int`.